# Polyline - smoothing and extracting specific turning points

Tags: optimization, algebraic-curves

I have a problem where I am given multiple polylines constructed from data points. I have to analyse these lines to fine a specific pattern. I am looking for a rise followed by a plateau of values followed by a decline. This pattern can be followed by a relaunch. I have added an image to illustrate. Please ignore the red polyline and excuse my crude drawing skills.

[image: Depiction of the polyline and the pattern I'd want to match!]

Another example with a zero plateau:

[image]

These are examples and to not have to be matched exactly. Any solution that comes closes to the desired outcome is mightily appreciated as I could build upon it. I have tried a few approaches but they all, for different reasons, seems to be sub-optimal.

**Selecting pseudo-turning points**
This method simply tries to retrieve specific data points to artificially create the desired polyline pattern. I am talking about pseudo-turning points because they are not really turning points. An example, selecting the leftmost and lowest point as the point where the first line will begin its rise might be flawed. There might be a series of smaller rises and declines before the sought steep rise to the plateau. Hence, the selected point would not be optimal.

**[Ramer-Douglas-Peucker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm)**
I tried applying algorithms, the one in the title for example, to the solution. It will smoothen my polyline but unfortunately, it might also loose the desired characteristics of the polyline.

**Finding all turning points by using derivatives**
As the polilines are constructed by datasets rather than equations, I'd need to find the equations first. I am not sure how scalable this solution would be as I have never done it before. I also highly doubt that this solution would be effective as even if I would find all concrete turning points, I'd still have to write an algorithm to parse them and check for an optimal solution. I predict the problem mentioned earlier in the first section would again be a non negligible issue.

Comment: This looks difficult, to me. You don't have a clear definition of "turning point", except that it's a place where the curve appears to be turning. This seems like one of those irritating problems that are very easy for human beings and very difficult for computers.

Comment: I completely agree. I'd also gladly accept algorithms for smoothing curves that are able to conserve the characteristics I need, even if they are averaged or slightly altered.

Comment: Is there some small number of patterns that can appear in the dataset. For example, do you know that the only occuring patterns are up-flat-down, or flat-up-down-flat, or something like that? If you do, there is some hope of fitting each one of these patterns to the data, and then choosing the one that's the best fit.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The polyline can take on any form. I'd discard those that do not fit the pattern and analyse those that do.

Comment: Do the data points represent measurements of some sort? If so, is it measurment error that's causing all the wiggles? And, can you estimate the likely size of the errors?

Comment: Do you know the minimum "wavelength" of the regions you're looking for. Could we say, for example, that an "upwards climbing" region that spans less than 5 time periods is not really an "up".

Comment: The data points represent measurements in time. They gather the consumption of a population regarding a specific product along its life cycle. As such, there are no errors that would cause any jiggling of the measurements. The regions can be dynamic in size. For example, a product that never took off might only have been on the rise for a few weeks while other products might maintain a plateau of years.